# Excel 2002 VBA compile error with code for later versions of Excel

Tags: excel, vba, compilation, version

I'm trying to use the following code in a spreadsheet that will be used across a wide range of versions of Excel :-

```
Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
```

If I include this code as normal, it will not compile under Excel 2002, but will work fine in later versions. I don't think the .ClearToMatchStyle command is available in Excel 2002, and this is where it's falling down.

Is there a way I can use the code above, but only activate the commands if a version of Excel later than 2002 is found ?

Many thanks for any help,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have too many options, really.

The one you've got is late binding for everything that is version-dependent.
That is:

```
Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

dim LateBoundChart As Object
set LateBoundChart = ActiveChart

on error resume next
LateBoundChart.ClearToMatchStyle
on error goto 0
```

Instead of the `on error resume next` you can:

- Jump to a more meaningful error handler.
- Check Excel version first, using `Application.Version`.

And in order to avoid the tedious `dim whatever as Object`, you can have a function:

```
public function LateBound(byval o as object) as Object
  set LateBound = o
end function
```

and then:

```
Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

on error resume next
LateBound(ActiveChart).ClearToMatchStyle
on error goto 0
```

Comment: That's very useful to know, thanks very much for your help with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for this extra information, and taking the time to think about the extra function side of things, I've learnt quite a lot just from this one answer. Many thanks.